# OpenLayers 3 ol.View extent not set

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to set the extent of a map view. Here is my code:

```
var viewOpts = {
    extent: [-2750000, -900000, 3600000, 4630000]
}

myMap.setView( new ol.View( viewOpts ) );
```

The view extent is returned as undefined. Any ideas on how I can get this to work. Using v3.15.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you [read about](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.View.html) the `extent` property of the `ol.View` it says that the `extent` constrains the `center` so the center cannot be outside of the extent.  So just add a center property that is inside the extent.  OL3 provides some [utilities](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.extent.html) for working with extents:

```
var extent = [-2750000, -900000, 3600000, 4630000];
var center = ol.extent.getCenter(extent);
map.setView(new ol.View({
  extent: extent,
  center: center
}));
```